# Why can I change a list inside a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, immutability

I have read that tuples are immutable. But this works fine:

```py
t=(1,[2,3,4])
t[1][1]=9
```

Also, I tried printing their `id` to see whether their ids are different as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015698/python-tuple-is-immutable-so-why-can-i-add-elements-to-it) question, but they are the same.

So I am confused, can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Are you mutating the tuple or the array? Try `t[1] = 9 `

Comment: @JonSG mutaing the array which is an element of tuple.

Comment: The immutability applies to the tuple itself (you cannot change its elements, ex. `t[1] = 9`) but not to its individual elements which can be mutable.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thanks for the linked question, my query is resolved because of it, I was unable to find it neither it was suggested while posting question.